# XCode 9.2 'shared_timed_mutex' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.12

Tags: mutex, shared

I don't normally post on here but this is driving me nuts.  I'm running Mac OS 10.13.3 with XCode 9.2 which is giving the error  "'shared_timed_mutex' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.12".  Does anyone know the reason for this?

Comment: So for some reason XCode is ignoring the deployment target set in the build settings, does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

change your deployment target from 10.11 to 10.12 or 10.13 will allow you to use 10.12 functionalities. The Xcode error message should make it clear how you can fix it

Comment: So I figured out that I was using an old build of UE4 which was compiled prior to 10.12 so the only solution was to rebuild UE4 from source.  Thanks for your help though!